# When is it recommended to pass a parameter as a query string and when should they be passed in the URL's path?

Tags: javascript, url, web

Are there any best practices when a parameter should be passed via URL's path instead of a query string?

**/test/foo vs /test?id=foo**

Comment: I think this is mostly a cosmetic concern.

Comment: passing parameters using url exposes your parameter data at client end however if you encrypt paramters still there is url size limit which restrict you the no of characters url support.

Comment: @sanki different strokes for different folks i guess...

Comment: By the time you want to express more than one concern in a URL, I would opt for query strings.

Comment: This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) might give you some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx) is very informative tutorial about your question. Its all about URL routes and every url can't be mapped as route if you are not following pattern for your site. and benefit of route is ease of readability nothing else.